# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'madlibs_project' django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have tried all the solutions I have seen, but I am still having the same error. I am trying to populate my database with some fake data generated in the file below:

population_madlibs_app.py

```
import random
from madlibs_app.models import User
from faker import Faker
import django
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'madlibs_project.settings')

django.setup()

fakegen = Faker()

fname = ['Charles', 'Stephen', 'Mike', 'Cornell', 'John', 'Yemi', 'Tomiwa']
lname = ['Nurudeen', 'Ayotunde', 'Ajiteru',
         'Kolade', 'Babatunde', 'Ifeanyi', 'Ola']
email_client = ['yahoo.com', 'gmail.com', 'outlook.com']


def add_user():
    fname = random.choice(fname)
    lname = random.choice(lname)
    emailed = '{}.{}@{}'.format(fname, lname, random.choice(email_client))
    ur = User.objects.get_or_create(
        first_name=fname, last_name=lname, email=emailed)[0]
    ur.save()
    return ur


def populate(n=1):
    for entry in range(n):
        create_user = add_user()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Processing...')
    populate(10)
    print('Succesfully created!')
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Madlibs\Desktop\madlibs\madlibs_project\population_madlibs_app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from madlibs_app.models import User
  File "C:\Users\Madlibs\Desktop\madlibs\madlibs_project\madlibs_app\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class User(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Madlibs\anaconda3\envs\madlibs\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 127, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\Madlibs\anaconda3\envs\madlibs\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Madlibs\anaconda3\envs\madlibs\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready      
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I have checked and seen several solutions, including the set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=madlibs_project.settings in cmd virtual env but still no solution.

This is my settings.py file.

```
"""
Django settings for madlibs_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, "static")


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-t-pby@4p3a%mpz2r_w3)d(7msdnrx@wl-yolws*hu5&owb7jq%"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "madlibs_app.apps.MadlibsAppConfig",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "madlibs_project.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "madlibs_project.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator", },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator", },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator", },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are trying to import a model before `django.setup()`.
Try to change your code to this, note `django.set()` is moved before importing the model.

```
import django
import random
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'madlibs_project.settings')

django.setup()


from madlibs_app.models import User
from faker import Faker


fakegen = Faker()

fname = ['Charles', 'Stephen', 'Mike', 'Cornell', 'John', 'Yemi', 'Tomiwa']
lname = ['Nurudeen', 'Ayotunde', 'Ajiteru',
         'Kolade', 'Babatunde', 'Ifeanyi', 'Ola']
email_client = ['yahoo.com', 'gmail.com', 'outlook.com']


def add_user():
    fname = random.choice(fname)
    lname = random.choice(lname)
    emailed = '{}.{}@{}'.format(fname, lname, random.choice(email_client))
    ur = User.objects.get_or_create(
        first_name=fname, last_name=lname, email=emailed)[0]
    ur.save()
    return ur


def populate(n=1):
    for entry in range(n):
        create_user = add_user()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Processing...')
    populate(10)
    print('Succesfully created!')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had looked at this for three days and didn't notice that was the issue. It worked!

Comment: I am happy this helped you. You can accept the answer so that others can also benefit.

Comment: I'm new on this platform, I'm being told I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote